# Efficient Way of Copying DynaBean

Tags: java, apache, delay, jprofiler

I was investigating my application using JProfiler and saw some delay which was caused by org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.copyProperties(new,old);

I need to ask whether this delay has any significance ? and is there a way I can enhance it using some other way ?

Image from JProfiler:
http://oi40.tinypic.com/2rn8sio.jpg

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem is not in the `copyProperties` but in the `getObject` getter that is called by it.

It looks like the getter is calling the database in order to get its value.

Comment: But I guess this getObject is called from CopyProperties() method.

Comment: Yes it is. Probably it iterates over all properties and copies them to a new object.